# pandas values change with numpy, but their memory locations are different

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy, memory-address

I created an array based on a dataframe. When I changed the value of the array the dataframe also changed, which means that both should be using the same address, but when I use id() to check it, it is different.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'column1': [11,22,33],
    'column2': [44,55,66]
})

col1_arr = df['column1'].to_numpy()
col1_arr[0] = 100
```

`col1_arr`

array([100,  22,  33], dtype=int64)

`df`

| index | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 44 |
| 1 | 22 | 55 |
| 2 | 33 | 66 |

When I changed the value of the array, the dataframe also changed to 100. If their values change to synchronize, it means they should be using the same memory address, but below shows that their addresses are different.

```py
for i in df['column1']:
    print(i)
    print(hex(id(i)))
    
# 100
# 0x21c795a0d50
# 22
# 0x21c795a0390
# 33
# 0x21c795a04f0
```

```py
for i in col1_arr:
    print(i)
    print(hex(id(i)))
# 100
# 0x21c00e36c70
# 22
# 0x21c00e36d10
# 33
# 0x21c00e36c70
```

Another strange thing is that the address of col1_arr[0] is equal to col1_arr[2].

Answer (score 0):

One column of the frame is a Series:

```
In [675]: S = df['column1']  
In [676]: type(S)
Out[676]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

While the storage details of a DataFrame, or Series, may vary, here it looks like the values are stored in a numpy array:

```
In [677]: S._values
Out[677]: array([11, 22, 33], dtype=int64)    
In [678]: id(S._values)
Out[678]: 2737259230384
```

And that array is exactly the same one that you get with `to_numpy()`:

```
In [679]: id(col1_arr)
Out[679]: 2737259230384
```

So when you change an element of `col1_arr`, you see that change in `S`, and `df`.

Data in an array is not stored by reference (not like `list`):

`col1_arr[0]` creates a `numpy.int64` object that has the same value, but it is not in any way the "address" of the value.  Note the different id values below:

```
In [683]: id(col1_arr[0])
Out[683]: 2737348615568
In [684]: id(col1_arr[0])
Out[684]: 2737348615280
```

To find "where" values are stored you have to look at something like:

```
In [686]: col1_arr.__array_interface__
Out[686]: 
{'data': (2737080083824, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3,),
 'version': 3}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, they are clear and understandable.